# How I should extract some information from my value JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have one value in my JSON file and I want to extract some information from my JSON file , How I should do this?

```
"audio_services": "{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"network addresses\",\"audio_ip_1\":\"ports\",\"audio_port_1\":\"media clock rate\"}",
```

imaginge in this code,I want to extract : "etwork addresses" , "ports" ,"media clock rate".

Comment: You need to convert the "audio_services" string into a JSON Object

Comment: JSON-inside-JSON is *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: The general approach is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JSON.parse` function to change your JSON string into an object.
You can then access the property of this object using the `.` accessor, or the bracket (`[ ]`)  accessor.

```js
let audioObject = "{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"network addresses\",\"audio_ip_1\":\"ports\",\"audio_port_1\":\"media clock rate\"}";

let object = JSON.parse(audioObject);
console.log(object['node-input-audio_services1'], ',', object['audio_ip_1'], ',', object['audio_port_1']);
```